# How to build yaml-cpp without CMake

Tags: c++, makefile, shared-libraries, static-libraries, yaml-cpp

I need to use yamp-cpp for a university project. For that, i plan to include the sources of yamp-cpp in a "lib" folder to be able to build the library and then my project.

The thing is that i cannot use CMake (can't install it where i will be demoing the project), and i dont know how to build this lib from command line (or makefile).

I've built simple c++ programs from command line, but i cannot get this working (tried to inspect the output from CMake but it is huge)

Can anyone tell me the lines i need to execute in order to build the lib and then link it to, say, a sample main.cpp?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add all .cpp files to your makefile. The CMake file doesn't do anything special.

Be sure that the headers are visible to your project. The public headers are all included as `"yaml-cpp/foo.h"` (so depending on where you put the `yaml-cpp` folder, make sure its parent directory is in your include path. The private headers are include as `"foo.h"`, so make sure that their folder is also in your include path.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. What would you recommend: build it each time i build my project, or build it once and then just link to it (like when in .net you reference a dll and then use it)

Comment: It's normally easiest to build it once and link to it, but since you're planning on building the whole project during your demo, it won't save on compilation time. However, you might want to build it as a library and link to it for practice!